# Oracle Service Bus echoing Soap request when a fault occurs

Tags: java, soap, weblogic, osb

I am experiencing a problem with soap webservices: when a fault occurs, the request gets echoed as a response.

The flow of the request is the following:

```
Html -> OSB#1 -> Java -> OSB#2 -> BackEnd Service
```

When the input request raises no errors, I get what was expected and everything works fine.

Instead, when I should be getting an error, some weird stuff happens:

1. If I call the service from the debugging console of OSB#2, I get the error message I expected.
2. If I call from the OSB#1 (or Html aswell) I get a Java error (XMLStreamReaderException) because OSB#2 echoed the XML I sent as a request.

My question is: is this a documented behaviour? How can I avoid it?

I tried googling, but I didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure where I should refer you regarding the documentation of this behavior, but I had the same issue. In order to get an SOAP fault whenever an error occurs, in all your proxy services:

1. Add an **Error Handler** to the service
2. Add a **Stage** inside the error handler
3. Add a **Reply** inside the stage and select the *With Error* option

So the flow will be like below:

[image]

Comment: I already have an Error Handler, when I call the service using the console inside the OSB#2, I get a SOAP Fault.

Instead, when I call OSB#2 from SoapUI, the request just gets echoed.

Did this ever happen to you? I just don't understand how the responses can be different

Comment: Hmm weird... The other thing I can think of is that you have a branch node, but you are not handling the specific operation you are calling from SoapUI. Maybe that's the case? The debugger can help you with this

Comment: I'd love it to be that way, but I'm calling the same branch node both from SoapUI and OSBconsole. I guess I'll look a bit more into the error handler. Thanks a lot for the input!

Comment: Hey, I encountered something that is very similar today, maybe the service requires WS authentication and you are missing the authentication header?

Comment: Hi, right now I can't verify this, because the backend was changed and fixed, and also the bus part has been modified. But I'm pretty sure this should be the case, since we had some problems with the authentication header not being added by the Java section. If you edit you answer with this comment, I'm gonna accept it. Thanks for sharing the knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

Request is echoed when you are not using the route node. I am not really clear about how are you making call to OSB#2 - is it through Java code which you call or through Service callout?